# Locked out of computer since install crashed

Tags: software-installation

So foolishly I fully installed elementary OS over Ubuntu earlier from USB.

The install crashed, and the dialogue box telling me this wouldn't close. I could only get rid of this by unplugging the computer from power.

Now when I power my computer on I get the usual grub menu asking if I would like to try elementary or install etc. but whichever option I choose I just get a black screen.

Is there any way out of this hole I've dug for myself?

I should also mention that the computer is an old iMac.

Any help that will stop me getting fired will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to reinstall elementary OS, or to restore macOS? Did you try to set up dual boot, to did you try to replace macOS with elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

Learn about boot repair and super grub2 disk, and eventually rescatux. For an old mac I recommand to install rEFIt from mac os X if you still have it.

Can you boot from live usb? If yes I think the best choice for you wood be to format your disk ( Create new GPT partition table, and loose all the data on the computer!) and then clean install elementary os 0.3.2 . If you have 0.3 or 0.3.1 downloaded it is important to download again.

An other thing thing that you can try is pressing alt or C during boot process, you will need a wired keyboard (I think).

I am currently using an old macbook.

Comment: If you are a new linux user or need more detail post back